# Spring REST post process all HTTP requests

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, jax-rs

## What I'm Trying to accomplish

I want to be able to process the results of a HTTP request to a Spring RestController after a particular endpoints method has returned it's value. E.g. I have:

```
GET /customer/{id}
```

This normally just returns a custom resource. It's endpoint I define in my `RestController` just returns a customer object.

I want to be able to modify the `HttpEntity` response that is crafted from this return result. In particular, I want to do all HATEOAS work in this post-processor and wrap it in my parent object.

What would be the best way to accomplish this? I would include what I've tried, but I can't think of any way this could be done cleanly.

In frameworks that implement JAX-RS, all you would need to do is implement the `ContainerResponseFilter` interface and you could add it to your REST server. This was simple to do with Jersey OR CXF.

Is there a notion of `ContainerResponseFilter` in Spring REST?

Comment: You can add After advice for a particular REST Controller method and perform the specific processing you.

Comment: Never worked with AOP before. Got an example for me?

Comment: Also, this might not work. I want to wrap my Customer object in another object, and return that as part of the HttpEntity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think, what you need is [ResponseBodyAdvice](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ResponseBodyAdvice.html).

As per documentation ,

> Allows customizing the response after the execution of an
>   @ResponseBody or a ResponseEntity controller method but before the
>   body is written with an HttpMessageConverter.
>
> Implementations may be may be registered directly with
>   RequestMappingHandlerAdapter and ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver or
>   more likely annotated with @ControllerAdvice in which case they will
>   be auto-detected by both.

Your other concern about `OutputStream` will be resolved and body will directly be available ,

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomerResponseFilter implements ResponseBodyAdvice<ResponseEntity<Customer>> {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(MethodParameter returnType,
        Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
    }

    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<Customer> beforeBodyWrite(ResponseEntity<Customer> body,
        MethodParameter returnType, MediaType selectedContentType,
        Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> selectedConverterType,
        ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response) {

    //..do your manipulations 
    return body;
    }

}
```

Since it is annotated with `@ControllerAdvice`, it will be automatically detected for your controllers.

Comment: Beautiful. This might be the golden answer

Comment: The only thing missing from this is that it only lets you modify the object itself, and you can't wrap it like I wanted to. In any case, it suits my needs as I am using a workaround for what I wanted. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can write an Spring MVC Interceptor and put it over the Controller method you want and you can use the `postHandle` method to do what you want to do.

Have a look at this [post](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-handler-interceptors-example/)

Comment: Hmm, while this gives me access to the request/response, it's in the form of an OutputStream. Which I have to read back into an object, might be difficult if I'm returning sometimes lists of customers, single customer object, other data models...